# Avoiding duplicate data when using multiple tasks

Tags: c#, producer-consumer, multitasking

Im trying to run a producer consumer pattern on my code to make it faster. My process is that I want to use multiple tasks running at the same time, for getting data, wrapping it in a custom class Product and then adding the product to a queue. Then the consumer saves it in the DB through Entity Framework through a single task. I tested the code I have now by inserting around 1000 products in the database, and then running sql query to check for duplicate rows.
[SQL Query result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R7EVy.png)

As you can see on the picture around 30 products appear more then once in the database.

This is my code:

```
public static void GetAllProductsFromIndexes_AndPutInDB(List<IndexModel> indexes, ProductContext context)
{
    BlockingCollection<IndexModel> inputQueue = CreateInputQueue(indexes);
    BlockingCollection<Product> productsQueue = new BlockingCollection<Product>(500);

    var consumer = Task.Run(() =>
    {
        foreach (Product readyProduct in productsQueue.GetConsumingEnumerable())
        {
            InsertProductInDB(readyProduct, context);
        }
    });

    var producers = Enumerable.Range(0, 25)
        .Select(_ => Task.Run(() =>
        {
            foreach (IndexModel index in inputQueue.GetConsumingEnumerable())
            {
                Product product = new Product();
                byte[] unconvertedByteArray;
                string xml;
                string url = @"https://data.Icecat.biz/export/freexml.int/en/";

                unconvertedByteArray = DownloadIcecatFile(index.IndexNumber.ToString() + ".xml", url);
                xml = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(unconvertedByteArray);
                XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
                xmlDoc.LoadXml(xml);

                GetProductDetails(product, xmlDoc, index);

                XmlNodeList nodeList = (xmlDoc.SelectNodes("ICECAT-interface/Product/ProductFeature"));
                product.FeaturesLink = GetProductFeatures(product, nodeList);

                nodeList = (xmlDoc.SelectNodes("ICECAT-interface/Product/ProductGallery/ProductPicture"));
                product.Images = GetProductImages(nodeList);
                productsQueue.Add(product);
            }
        })).ToArray();

    Task.WaitAll(producers);

    productsQueue.CompleteAdding();

    consumer.Wait();
}
```

All in all my question is what can I do to avoid this happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid duplication try adding new field to Product table and lets name it `Code` which contains the hash of the product`s xml.
And make sure to add unique attribute to it.
this way any attempt to add a duplication will fail due to the unique constraint/index.

```cs
public static string Hash(string input)
{
    var hash = new SHA1Managed().ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input));
    return string.Concat(hash.Select(b => b.ToString("x2")));
}

public static void GetAllProductsFromIndexes_AndPutInDB(List<IndexModel> indexes, ProductContext context)
{
    BlockingCollection<IndexModel> inputQueue = CreateInputQueue(indexes);
    BlockingCollection<Product> productsQueue = new BlockingCollection<Product>(500);

    var consumer = Task.Run(() =>
    {
        foreach (Product readyProduct in productsQueue.GetConsumingEnumerable())
        {
            InsertProductInDB(readyProduct, context);
        }
    });

    var producers = Enumerable.Range(0, 25)
        .Select(_ => Task.Run(() =>
        {
            foreach (IndexModel index in inputQueue.GetConsumingEnumerable())
            {
                Product product = new Product();
                byte[] unconvertedByteArray;
                string xml;
                string url = @"https://data.Icecat.biz/export/freexml.int/en/";

                unconvertedByteArray = DownloadIcecatFile(index.IndexNumber.ToString() + ".xml", url);
                xml = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(unconvertedByteArray);
                XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
                xmlDoc.LoadXml(xml);

                GetProductDetails(product, xmlDoc, index);

                XmlNodeList nodeList = (xmlDoc.SelectNodes("ICECAT-interface/Product/ProductFeature"));
                product.FeaturesLink = GetProductFeatures(product, nodeList);

                nodeList = (xmlDoc.SelectNodes("ICECAT-interface/Product/ProductGallery/ProductPicture"));
                product.Images = GetProductImages(nodeList);
                product.Code= Hash(xml);
                productsQueue.Add(product);
            }
        })).ToArray();

    Task.WaitAll(producers);

    productsQueue.CompleteAdding();

    consumer.Wait();
}
```

Comment: Sure but now it just throws a dbupdateexception instead of moving on to the next entry?

Comment: you can wrap the save changes code in try catch block. you can also check for Product Code before trying to insert it.please share your insertion to database code so I can provide more helpful solution